# Setting an Image using ImageView in Coding

Tags: android, imageview

Below is my code, this closes the app as I have set the image in my class. What seems wrong with this? Easier way to load the image?

```
public static class FiveSkills extends Activity{
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.five_skills);
    }
}
```

XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Five Skills"
    android:textColor="#08088A"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that by the time you are using the method, findViewById(R.id.img), your views might not even been inflated yet, in order for the code to work get areference to the image after setContentView is called, something like this:

```
ImageView img;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.five_skills);
}
```

Hop this helps.

Regards!

Comment: "might not" --> "will not"

Comment: If the answer was helpful don't forget marking it as correct, so people would take time to answer your further questions...

Answer (score 1):

Best way to get the child view is once it's parent is inflated. That's the only reason you are getting `"ANR"`.

Seems like you mixed up the concept of Java grabbing variables next to classes and make it global. Exactly right that's the we way always do. But when it comes to grab view from `XML Layout` file. You need to inflate it which happens at the start of `Activity` under `onCreate()`. It's always better to have a look at life cycle of things which you working on. So go and google out `Life Cycle of Activity` FYI.

Your Code would looks something like these :

```
public static class FiveSkills extends Activity
{
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.image);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img); // Inflate child view once your parentview is available.
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.five_skills);
   }
}
```

Once you get the layout file which you gonna use it in your `Activity`. After that you are ready to pull down layout children view.